# In Windows Active Driectory, what's the purpose of SIDs when the username is already unique?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-authentication

A **Windows ID** (*such as MyDomain\someuser*) will have a unique **SID** (*such as S-1-5-21-1695517229-881958489-217698969-1001*)

The **ID** is used during login, which confirms that it too is unique in nature.

What's the purpose of the **SID** then?

Seems like a redundant primary key to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference is that a [*Security Identifier*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers) (SID) is **immutable**, whereas both [*SAM Account Name*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties#samaccountname) (`CONTOSO\USERNAME`) and [*User Principal Name*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties#userprincipalname) (UPN, `username@contoso.com`) can be changed.

In a Windows Active Directory domain a user might have permissions to resources across many servers and workstations. If all those permissions were bound to usernames, changing usernames would be impossible. As usernames typically are based on real names and people do get married etc., that would be quite impractical.

Comment: +1 To getting married... didn't think about that!

Comment: Some even keep both surnames, causing their real names become too long for the SAM Account Name. That's so reckless! Apparently being in love makes them completely forget about their kind IT administrators. ;)

Comment: IT administrator are always in love :) But not to a human!